# nullable bool in if() statement - checks required?

Tags: c#, nullable

I just came across this in a coworkers code. He has a nullable bool type that he compares like this:

```
//foo has no value here and evaluated to false
if(foo==true)
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Typically, the way I check a nullable boolean is something like this:

```
bool IsTrue(bool? value)
{
   return value.HasValue && value.Value;
}

if(IsTrue(foo)){
   doSomething()
}
```

**Edit: I ran through both methods and they both appear work the same way. I'm asking which one is the correct way and if the extra checks are necessary??**

Now I am questioning both myself and my coworkers code. Is there any point in me doing this extra check here? Or can I safely do it the first way?

Thanks (and yes I did search for this! :))

Comment: Why don't you try it out for yourself? In a unit test or for example LINQPad.

Comment: @Honza I know that both statements work. I'm asking which one is the correct one to use

Comment: To be fair, I'd question the need for a nullable boolean value. Most times something is either true or false, it's not "in the middle" or "half true half false".

Comment: for me, `if(foo)` does not work. Compiler says: "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*"

Comment: @Arran Very often the case is that something can be `true`, `false` or `unknown`.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I didn't say there were never cases that is true, I just said I'd question it personally. Since there isn't much context to the code, who can say? If you can attach more semantic meaning to something then you should do just that.

Comment: @w0lf good catch! it actually says if(foo==true)

Comment: `==true` and `IsTrue` both seem unclear. Personally I would write out `foo.HasValue && foo.Value` every time, or at least use something like `!IsNullOrFalse(foo)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually I don't recommend you to treat `null` as `false`. Either use non-nullable boolean, or explicitly handle `null` value. One more option to do that:

```
if (foo ?? false)
{

}
```

Comment: thanks. I like this. This will always do the same thing as if(foo==true) though, correct? I realize it makes it more clear to the user that it's possible to have a null value.. but functionality wise, it is the same?

Comment: @dferraro from terms of performance most efficient will be `HasValue && Value` call, or `GetValueOrDefault()`. But both null-coalescing operator and comparing with boolean value use `GetValueOrDefault()` and additional `HasValue` call (checked on .Net 4.5). I tend to write readable code instead of doing premature optimizations, so I'd go with `foo ?? false` or `foo.HasValue && foo.Value`. `GetValueOrDeault()` is also good option, but `foo == true` makes me stop and think a little, which I don't like to do when reading code

Answer (score 7):

I'd use this.

```
bool IsTrue(bool? value)
{
   return value.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

This will return false when `null` or `false` and `true` only when it has a value and `true`.

Note: You **cannot** use `bool?` in `if statement`, as if statement `requires` anything which is implicitly convertible to `Boolean`. where as `bool?` is not convertible to boolean, so compiler will complain.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky it's nice, but I find comparing to `true` more explicit, and thus better. Here you need to remember what the default is - therefore it's less explicit.

Comment: @BartoszKP So you mean you don't know what is default value of `bool`? Or anybody dont know that? I don't think so..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No. I mean what I've said, and only this. It's less explicit, and that's all. What I (or the reader) know or not is irrelevant :)

Comment: thanks. I like this. This will always do the same thing as if(foo==true) though, correct? I realize it makes it more clear to the user that it's possible to have a null value.. but functionality wise, it is the same?

Comment: If you don't want to rely on the default value of `bool` you can use the [overload of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify your default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this by checking for the value to be `true`, like this:

```
bool IsTrue(bool? value)
{
   return value == true;
}
```

This will work for `null`s as well, returning `false`.

I prefer using this check "inline", without an additional function, because it is short and clean:

```
if(foo == true){
   doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

since this doesnt compile

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool? test = null;
        if (test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

i would do something like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool? test = null;
        if (test ?? false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

but there is a million way of doing this so pick one and stick with it :-)

Comment: was a type in my psuedo code. The real code says if(foo==true).. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check if the bool has value first.

I would do as you first proposed:

```
value.HasValue && value.Value
```

As it is most clear to people reading the code.